# How to understand given recursion problem?

Tags: java, recursion

I am learning about Java in [www.w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com) and I've got in Recursion topic. Can someone please explain the way this code works?
The output is 45, but I don't really understand how can I get it especially this part
return end + sum(start, end - 1);

```
    public class Main {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
        int result = sum(5, 10);
        System.out.println(result);
      }
      public static int sum(int start, int end) {
        if (end > start) {
          return end + sum(start, end - 1);
        } else {
          return end;
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Recursion is no different to invoking any other method; it just happens to be the same method. Work it through on paper: when you invoke `sum(5, 10)`, you end up returning `10 + sum(5, 10 - 1)`. Repeat this to work out what `sum(5, 9)` is; keep going until there are no more recursive calls.

Comment: "Community" gave you the answer below.  What they're doing is called "hand execution."  Basically you follow the steps in a program and write down on a piece of paper what each calculation gives you.  At the end you should have the correct answer, the same as the computer gives you.  It's an excellent (I'd say necessary) technique to understand what code is really doing.

Comment: Thanks for help guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replacing the values into the formula, you could do something like:

`sum(5,10) = end + sum(start,end-1)`
`sum(5,10) = 10  + sum(5    ,10 -1)`
and so on.

Note: each call to `sum` has its own parameter, so the previous value is not changed on next call.

Comment: So basically the summing part is  END + sum(start, END -1) and the start Is just here for loop area right? I hope you understood my explanation.

Comment: More or less, but  `end` is also used to loop (it is decremented until it is no longer greater than `start`).